# Array class Fatal error c++

Tags: arrays, class

When trying to define a class that contains an array of 5 elements, defaulted to zero, I receive the following error

Header file

```
class Array 
{ 
public:
Array (int =5);  //Initialize the array with 0 values

private:
int size;   // size of created array
int*  arr;
};
```

Source

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Array.h"
using namespace std;
Array::Array (int i)
{

arr = new int[5];
for(int j = 0; j<size; j++)
    *(arr + i) = 0;
}
```

Driver

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Array.h"
using namespace std;
void main()
{
Array a;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You do not initialize `Array::size`. Initialize `Array::size` before using it in the constuctor.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your reply but I found my mistake. I knew that once I found it it would be something silly and it was. I my driver was a .h file instead of a .cpp. Sorry for taking up your time.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't mention what the error is. Can it compile at this point?

Second, you don't seem to be setting the size in your constructor there, so nothing would be set there (as @Oswald said)

Third, you should be using array notation. EX:

```
arr[i]='\0'
```

fourth, you change variables have way through your loop. you initialize J, then change it to I . Make sure you are using the same variable throughout

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

```
Array::Array (int i): size(i)  // <-- initialise size with i
{
    arr = new int[5]; //Should be: new int[size];
                  ^ 5?? How about using size that we receive as parameter??

    for(int j = 0; j<size; j++)
        *(arr + i) = 0;
                ^ Here is the problem. Use *(arr + j)!
}
```

---

Other problems:

- Use a destructor! You are allocating using `new`, and you conveniently forget about `delete[]`
- `void main()` ? Use `int main() {...; return 0;}`